# Android adb no permission

Tags: android, udev, adb

I'm trying to use adb from a Ubuntu(+Cinnamon) machine. The problem is that I get following message from **adb devices**:

```
List of devices attached
TA8830OIVO  no permissions
```

Where TA8830OIVO is my Motorola G device.

I changed android rules in **/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules**

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="22b8", ATTR{idProduct}=="2e76",
MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev", SYMLINK+="android_adb", OWNER="axel"
```

I also restarted udev service and adb being installed on my personal laptop I'm the only user with all the priveledges needed (plugdev group and so on).

Is there a way to run adb without invoking **sudo**?

Comment: Restarting udev and `sudo udevadm trigger` didn't work for me. I had to restart the computer and then it worked just fine

Comment: refer: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/177318/why-cant-i-run-adb-via-udev/214369#214369

Answer (score 83):

Change the USB mode in your phone to File Transfer. That's what worked for me.

Comment: The opposite is true for me: USB debugging does not work during file transfer mode on some old devices.

Comment: Update: just noticed that in my phone (android one), usb debugging can also be enabled while in charging mode in Developer Settings.

Comment: Changing to file transfer mode worked for me. On android 7

Comment: Kindle Fire 8 2019 - "MTP mode" which is in USB configuration in Developer Options.

Comment: I changed and then i was prompted on the device to allow usb debugging :D

Comment: I was doing this as it made sense and then thought, "Oh probably don't need to" and here we are.

Answer (score 31):

1. Remember to run `sudo udevadm trigger` to get the changes applied (or reboot, but where's the fun in that).
2. Instead of writing your own rules use https://github.com/M0Rf30/android-udev-rules
3. Make sure you have the latest ADB version (1.0.35 102d0d1e73de-android). Earlier ones didn't work with USB-C for me.

Comment: Thanks but it's kinda old question. I switched to Mac 2 years ago. I find it stupid to do stuff like **lsusb** and then modify rules when it should be done automatically... I gave up after so many years of ubuntu use. Can't find a decent Linux Desktop system.

Comment: The question is 6 months old and still valid for posterity. 1y ago I dumped OS X after a 3y affair and went back to Linux for similar reasons ;).

Linux has parts where it gets frustrating but there's a similar amount of tinkering required in OS X if you use homebrew+zsh+iTerm2. The difference is that stuff if mostly closed-source or outdated versions of FOSS but with a nice GUI and UX (for the most part). 

Using the rules from the repo makes it mostly a one-time setup step. Considering the arcana of getting the Android SDK to work in a sane way it's toddlers-play.

Comment: Running this and `service udev restart` didn't work for me. I had to restart the computer and then it worked just fine.

Comment: On ubuntu 16.04 setting the udev rules, changing the usb mode on phone to file transfer worked like a charm. No restart needed.

Comment: On ubuntu 16.04 with a Pixel 2 adding the rules from the gitbub of point 2 works without even going in to file transfer mode.

Comment: second step was the one, that solved my problem

Answer (score 6):

If you restart the ADB server with sudo, it will work.

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
```

Answer (score 1):

For Amazon Fire OS 8, an Android based OS, you can go to "Settings > Device Options > Developer Options". You may need to [enable it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52195356/how-to-enable-developer-options-by-default-in-android-source).

Ensure "USB Debugging" is on (in your case, it is).

Then go to "Networking > Select USB Configuration". Choose "MTP (Media Transfer Protocol)". This allows the computer to send files back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

remove adb package installed via apt

```
$sudo apt remove adb
```

download latest adb from
 
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

set the path to platform tools(better put these two lines in ~/.bashrc file)

```
export PATH= /<path-to-android-sdk-folder>/android-sdk/tools/bin<br>
export PATH= /<path-to-android-sdk-folder>/android-sdk/platform-tools
```

run

```
$source ~/.bashrc
```

check adb path

```
$which adb
```

start adb in sudo(I needed to give absolute path to adb when running in sudo )

```
$sudo /<path-to-android-sdk-folder>/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
$sudo /<path-to-android-sdk-folder>/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
```

```
$adb shell
```

DONE.
it works irrespective of what USB mode( MIDI, transferring files, charging) of android phone. It works in all.

Answer (score 0):

Define custom gradle function:

```
task _adb_restart {
def adb = android.getAdbExe().toString()
group '__custom'
  doLast {
    exec {
      commandLine 'bash', '-c', '/bin/echo **root_password** | sudo -S ' + adb + ' kill-server'
    }
    exec {
      commandLine 'bash', '-c', '/bin/echo **root_password** | sudo -S ' + adb + ' devices'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution and what worked better for me is to install `adb` from Ubuntu package. This gives you a community-maintained default set of `udev` rules for all Android devices.

example:

```
$ sudo apt-get install adb
```